# AC Transformer Power Cable

Tags: ac, mains

I have recently purchases an 120 Vac to 12 Vac transformer similar in design to the one shown [here](http://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/MTEyMFgxNjAw/z/mgkAAMXQWx1RHS-F/%24T2eC16h,!yUE9s6NGYHtBRHS-E30nQ~~60_12.JPG). I am curious as to the best way to wire this up. I am not a big fan of making a suicide cable for the obvious reasons of electrocution. If I pick up a set of [these](http://i4.photobucket.com/albums/y147/Hampst6/tamc5106.jpg), would it be safe to splice and solder a 120Vac power cable into the connector?

Comment: Why not just use butt connectors?

Comment: I want the mains line the be detachable from the transformer.

Comment: Then get a proper AC jack and wire that on.

Comment: Then what does that look like.

Comment: They usually look [like this](http://i.imgur.com/dFG0J6t.jpg).

Comment: If I am not mistaken that appears to be a C8 Coupler correct?

Comment: Sounds about right, yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is some kind of IEC Power Entry component.
Digi-Key and other distributors have tons, with or without fuses, and with and without protective earthing.
Personally, I like using the ATX power supply style IEC C-14 connectors, because I have tons of those cables laying around.
This one also has a built-in fuse holder (remember to also get fuses!)
http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/723W-X2%2F03/Q205-ND/245546

Comment: Exactly. If it's just one off, find an old pc, take out the power supply and gut it. Gives you the connector and a proper enclosure for the transformer.

Comment: So I have built my 'special' cable. The thing scares the hell out of my personally. The real problem I have with the setup is the fact that I made it. Anyway I do intend to go with a C-14 style connector as I am planning on building a variable voltage ~5 Amp bench top power supply. My homemade cable would not be safe to run that high of a current through.